# Copy.asmx vs DocumentService.asmx to Upload files and related questions

Tags: web-services, file-upload

I have two applications which does the same thing - upload files to SharePoint folder; one is a Windows service and the other one is a batch file.

I wrote the application deployed as a Batch File and a former employee wrote the windows service.

The Windows service accomplishes the upload by `UploadFile()` method in `DocumentService.asmx` web service.

The Batch file accomplishes it by calling `CopyIntoItems()` method in `Copy.asmx` web service.

Once in a while, the `UploadFile()` fails when trying to upload larger files with `System.OutOfMemoryException`. It works fine for other files.

I do not know if `CopyIntoItems()` method will have a similar issue because it deals with much smaller files.

Here are my questions:

- Will adding memory help with this issue?
- If so, where should it be done - the server where the SP Web services are running or database server ?
- Is there a configuration item in `app.config` or elsewhere to specify memory?
- Should we expect the same issue if we switch to `Copy.asmx` to upload files?

The version I'm dealing with is SharePoint 2007

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489920/304661
- http://sharepoint.infoyen.com

Comment: Are the files greater than 50 MB? That can be configured in central admin. Otherwise, it sounds like you are running out of memory on the machine that is doing the uploading... Do you have a stack trace?